# Access all data from multiple Linked Tables in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, relationship

[image]

Now In all the 4 models i have provided relations as `hasmany()` and `belongsTo()` .

When I tried to access a particular city from the table and it's associated state using below code it's working fine.

```
 $citydetails=City_table::with('states')->find($id);
```

Now at the same time I also want to access the associated country name for the state. I tried doing this:

```
 $citydetails=City_table::with('states','countries')->find($id);
```

This gives me an error message, I know this way it wont work because city and country are not related to each other directly, but I need to access data like this, if I access a specific city then I want it's state as well as it's country in the result.

Comment: I think you have to use a dot notation to get nested relations. Something like `with('states.countries')`, will get states and their countries. Thats assuming your states model has a `countries()` method on it that handles the relation.

Comment: thanks buddy this worked with dot notation

Comment: Offtopic: Which app did you used to generate the graphic? I'm just curious.

Comment: Not the best one but useful http://diagrams.seaquail.net/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use dot notation to access nested relationships. To quote the [Laravel Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships).

> To eager load nested relationships, you may use "dot" syntax. For
>   example, let's eager load all of the book's authors and all of the
>   author's personal contacts in one Eloquent statement:
>
> `$books = App\Book::with('author.contacts')->get();`

In your case, this would look something like:

```
 $citydetails = City_table::with('states.countries')->find($id);
```